# mount.cifs: permission denied after upgrading to 20.10

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, cifs

I have a NAS that up to version 19 I could mount at startup through fstab with this command:

```
//192.168.1.99/data /home/user/data cifs username=uname,password=upwd,uid=user,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

After having upgraded to 20.10, this has stopped working, and a check using `mount -a` returns:  `mount.cifs: permission denied`.

I am still able to mount the drive using `sudo mount -a`, but how can I modify fstab to make it work again?

Comment: I would check the owner and permissions of the `/home/user/data` folder.  According to the `man mount` for "Non-superuser" mounts as long as you have the user specified in `fstab` it should work.

Comment: That actually did the trick, many thanks!
I wonder why there was no need for an `fstab` group before?

Comment: I have the same problem but I didn't understand how to solve it, can you explain it to a non-Linux expert? What should I add to my fstab?

Comment: @alebal, you need to create a group named fstab and add your userid to it. 

`sudo groupadd fstab` will create the group
`sudo adduser yourusername fstab` will add you to the group

Comment: @IncrediblyConvoluted I ran your commands, but after reboot still:mount.cifs: permission denied. I use this format: //fritz-nas/fritz.nas/PENNA_USB/FRITZ/NAS /media/NAS cifs username=myusername,password=mypassword,uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0, is something missing? It has always worked and with sudo mount -a it still works but at boot I don't have permission to access.

Comment: @IncrediblyConvoluted Still blocked... please help...

Comment: @alebal I'm afraid I can't help further than that, my knowledge ends right here. Hopefully someone else will be able to answer

Comment: same problem in raspberry pi with raspberry os

Comment: sudo chown myusername /media/NAS; sudo chmod 700 /media/NAS

Comment: Today even on LMDE, after a weird reboot of router and pc... weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.2.2/C /mnt/mountpoint -o credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8
```

If you get an error, you might be missing a utility:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

If you get a `no such file or directory` error, create the mountpoint:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/mountpoint
```

If you get a `permission denied` error, check the permissions:

```
ls -ld /mnt/mountpoint
```

You might have to change it:

```
sudo chown `whoami` /mnt/mountpoint 
sudo chmod 700 /mnt/mountpoint
```

Then try again. (Run `man chmod` to learn more.)

If it still doesn't work, tweak your options until it does. Also try with `sudo` for good measure, but it shouldn't be necessary.

For an easy:

```
mount /mnt/moutpoint
```

Make sure the mount you want is in `/etc/fstab`. If not, add it. `man fstab` for the format. Eg.

```
//192.168.2.2/C /mnt/mountpoint cifs credentials=/home/ubuntuusername/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 2 1
```

Where `~/.smbcredentials` contains:

```
user=myuser
password=mypass
domain=WORKGROUP
```

(Remember to `chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials`)

Then mount again:

```
mount /mnt/mountpoint
```

No need to be in a `fstab`, `sudo` or `mount` group.

Comment: Don't seems to work... says: sudo mount -a
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
but all dir are correct, they work with the other format just don't work on boot...

Comment: You definitely made a typo somewhere. Please share the string that doesn't work, and the one that works...

Comment: //fritz-nas/fritz.nas/PENNA_USB/FRITZ/NAS /media/NAS cifs username=myuser,password=mypssw,uid=1000,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,vers=1.0 0 0 this work with sudo mount -a, but not on boot

Comment: #//fritz-nas/fritz.nas/PENNA_USB/FRITZ/NAS /media/NAS cifs credentials=/home/pi/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8 2 1 this show the error with sudo mount -a